# how to make a fast mongodb aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have 3 collections of chats, users, messages.
[chats collection schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0nMT.png). [users collection schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sccK.png). [messages collection schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNaJu.png).

I just want to list recent chats with the latest message.
I'm using a query like below, but is very slow for too many messages per chats when I use a sort condition of created_at:-1. If I remove that sort statement, it will return the results very fast but not with the latest message.

```
    var pipeline = [
  {$match: {
    /* myId must be same to the user (creator) or person (contact) */
      $or:[
        {"user": ObjectId(req.query.user)},
        {"person": ObjectId(req.query.user)},
      ]
    }},
  /* creator  */
  {"$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "user",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "creator"
    }},
  {"$unwind": {
      "path": "$creator",
      //    "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": false
    }},
  /* contact  */
  {"$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "person",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "contact"
    }},
  {"$unwind": {
      "path": "$contact",
      //     "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": false
    }},
  /* latest message */
  {$lookup: {
      from: "chatmessages",
      let: {
        chatId: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: ["$chat", "$$chatId"]
            }
          }},

        /*  Here is the sort statement, -1 or 1 is not the problem. The problem is own sort */
        {$sort: {
            "created_at": -1
          },},
        {"$limit": 1},
      ],
      as: "messages"
    }},

  {$group : {
      _id : "$_id",
      msg : {"$last":"$messages"},
    }},

  /* ***  Projection to get the fields we want *** */
  {$project: {
      _id: 1, created_at:1,count:1,msg:1,
      creator: 1,contact:1, messages: 1,

      /*  conditional projection to get the last message from array of messages */
      lastMessage: {
        $arrayElemAt: ["$msg", 0]
      },
    }},
  /* ***  another $match to get chats which has message   *** */
  {$match: {
      lastMessage: {$exists: true}
    }},
  { "$sort": { created_at: -1 } },
  {"$limit": 20},
];
var resultants = await Chat.aggregate(pipeline);
```

And my results are :

```
{
"statusCode": 200,
"message": "Request Successfully Done but dependencies did not updated",
"error": false,
"results": [
    {
        "_id": "614ca0af08608f0a54f03024",
        "msg": [
            {
                "_id": "617049898196941fb05b78de",
                "filter_type": "text",
                "user": "614c9f6a9430631fc866f1f7",
                "chat": "614ca0af08608f0a54f03024",
                "body": "che hali daram emshab",
                "updated_at": "2021-10-20T16:53:29.705Z",
                "created_at": "2021-10-20T16:53:29.705Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "lastMessage": {
            "_id": "617049898196941fb05b78de",
            "filter_type": "text",
            "user": "614c9f6a9430631fc866f1f7",
            "chat": "614ca0af08608f0a54f03024",
            "body": "che hali daram emshab",
            "updated_at": "2021-10-20T16:53:29.705Z",
            "created_at": "2021-10-20T16:53:29.705Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "614ca0af08608f0a54f03022",
        "msg": [
            {
                "_id": "6170476dc2359d0e047584cd",
                "filter_type": "text",
                "user": "614c9f6a9430631fc866f1f9",
                "chat": "614ca0af08608f0a54f03022",
                "body": "moattalom kerdie hasan",
                "updated_at": "2021-10-20T16:44:29.135Z",
                "created_at": "2021-10-20T16:44:29.135Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "lastMessage": {
            "_id": "6170476dc2359d0e047584cd",
            "filter_type": "text",
            "user": "614c9f6a9430631fc866f1f9",
            "chat": "614ca0af08608f0a54f03022",
            "body": "moattalom kerdie hasan",
            "updated_at": "2021-10-20T16:44:29.135Z",
            "created_at": "2021-10-20T16:44:29.135Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    }
]
```

}

It takes 1140ms response time. Without sort statement for messages, it will be less than 300ms.
Please help me to solve this big problem.
Thank you

Comment: what version of mongodb you have? for index to be used in lookup pipeline with $expr you need >= MongoDB 5, i mean for this  `$eq: ["$chat", "$$chatId"]`

Comment: Hello @Takis_ . I have that version of mongodb

Comment: you have an index on  `"created_at"` on chatmessages? also you have real dates and not strings? if you have strings use real dates + create the index if you dont have it. maybe will help

Comment: dear @Takis_ ! thanks for answering and helping me. I had not an index by my fault.
And now I have an index for my messages created_at field. response time has been reduced to about 600ms. Do you think this response  time is good enough for a chat application?

Comment: i dont know maybe query can be faster, i see you do lookup and then uwind, if you dont the members of the array that you unwind for the next lookup,you can keep them as array, and unwind later maybe after all the lookups. (unwind produces many documents making lookup slower)

Comment: thank you so much. I will try to make it better. Thank you

Comment: also create index on `{"user": ObjectId(req.query.user)}, {"person": ObjectId(req.query.user)}` if you dont have already, and in all lookup fields if you dont have already (`_id` has already index) , try index on "$chat" also , gl

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Comment: Maybe change your data model. Your look more like an relational RDBMS design. Typically the number of collections in a NoSQL database is much less than the number of tables in a relational SQL database.

Comment: Why do you make `$lookup` on `users` for `user` and `person`? By running `{ $group: { _id: "$_id", msg: { $last: "$messages" } } }` you remove fields `contact` and `creator` again, so I don't see any reason to fetch them.

Comment: You right. But that was not a problem. My problem is the performance. my `created_at` is defined as an index, but as you said, I think this structure is not good enough for a `NOSQL` schema. So I'm working on the collections to make them better with highest performance.Thnaks

Comment: `{ $sort: { created_at: -1 } }` is also useless. There is not field `created_at` at this stage.

Comment: `chatmessages` has a `created_at` field. I tested that query and it worked. But for too much documents, takes too much time to send a response.

Comment: Then you would need `{ $sort: { "lastMessage.created_at": -1 } }`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data, this pipeline returns the same result:

```
db.chat.aggregate([
   { $match: { $or: [{ "user": user }, { "person": person },] } },
   {
      $lookup: {
         from: "chatmessages",
         let: { chatId: "$_id" },
         pipeline: [
            { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$chat", "$$chatId"] } } },
            { $sort: { "created_at": -1 }, },
            { "$limit": 1 },
         ],
         as: "messages"
      }
   },
   { $group: { _id: "$_id", lastMessage: { "$last": "$messages" } } },
   { $set: { lastMessage: { $first: "$lastMessage" } } },
   { "$limit": 20 }
])
```

A different approach could be this one:

```
db.chat.aggregate([
   { $match: { $or: [{ "user": user }, { "person": person },] } },
   {
      $lookup: {
         from: "chatmessages",
         localField: "_id",
         foreignField: "chat",
         as: "messages"
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         messages: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$messages",
               cond: { $eq: ["$$this.created_at", { $max: "$messages.created_at" }] }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $project: { lastMessage: { $last: "$messages" } } },
   { "$limit": 20 }
])
```

Comment: Dear friend! Thank you for your answer, but both of them return an internal server error.

Comment: What is the exact error? Perhaps a typo on your side? Again, please provide some sample input data.

Comment: The error code is `Location40324`. I'm completely confused. I just want a fast query to get last related document in `collection B` for each document in `collection A`, based on date.